# How to prevent outdoor landscape light water leaks?

Tags: lighting, leak, waterproofing, landscaping

I installed low voltage landscape lights on our fencing around the perimeter of our backyard in September. The lights are supposed to be IP66 waterproof, but within a month of installing, I found water pooling inside some of the units. I then disassembled, dried and sealed off anywhere I thought water could penetrate in with silicone in hopes that water would no longer seep in.

After re-wiring and installing, within a few weeks, water was beginning to pool inside again and some of the lights were starting to malfunction. Inside, some of the connections were corroding. I did notice that it appeared that most of the water was coming from condensation build-up, which then led me to believe that the water leak could be due to temperature/pressure changes.

From my research, it seems like this is a common problem, especially here in Western Canada where temperatures can change quite rapidly. I have seen some suggestions of installing small vents made of a waterproof breathable PTFE membrane on each of the units that are meant to allow for pressure equalization. I have also read that Gore-Tex clothing is made from a semi-permeable membrane, so I was thinking about creating a small hole in each unit and then creating a barrier for the hole with the Gore-tex.

I am wondering if anyone has any further suggestions on how to prevent this from happening? Or a cheaper/simpler permeable membrane material I could use. These were purchased from Amazon and I am past the return date so I'm stuck with them. I have spent a very unreasonable amount of time on these lights and I am hoping someone might have the answer. I have included some photos below as well.

[image: light 1]

[image: light 2]

[image: light disassembled]

[image: Parts & Other Angles]

Comment: you could try covering one or two of the units to prevent rain from reaching them ... see if it makes a difference ... perhaps a vent tube would work

Comment: I had experimented by taking 2 of lights and temporarily attaching them to my deck railing with NO power connected to either light. After several days, not a single drop of water entered either of the lights, which made me a bit more confident that the leaks were from the pressure equalization as the lights cycled on and off.

Comment: The PVC gasket may be the culprit to blame. Try adding a thin flexible gasket instead. Also, you might try to seal the gap between the glass and the light casing.

Comment: Obviously these lights are not good.   Why troubleshoot something that will keep having issues when these are $20 a piece to replace?   Just looking at the basic design... yep looks like they should leak.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if allowed in Canada but in the US we are allowed and even required to provide a drain in things like this a small drilled hole that will allow the water to drain out should eliminate the pooling.  I used to have multiple drains on my big 1000w metal halide lights because they cool in the winter they suck the water in just like yours. A small 1/8-1/4” hole at the lowest point will help no matter how the water is getting in.

Answer (score 1):

This does not necessarily meet your request for "cheaper", but I have 2 suggestions that otherwise will likely solve your problem:

1. Consider underwater pond lights. I use them above water along a creek bank that is prone to occasional flooding. After about a year or so, there have been no leak or condensation problems. This is in Texas, but they recently survived the February 0 degree F weather with no problem.
2. Buy from a supplier that has a more liberal (and easier) return policy for defective products. It could be a commercial product, as previously suggested. In my case, the source was Home Depot and I actually had to return several that were defective straight out of the box. Once we got past that issue, the ones in use have proved reliable.

Answer (score 0):

"The lights are supposed to be IP66 waterproof" That's not very helpful if, in reality, they clearly aren't. Unfortunately, you bought junk :( There may be some point to messing with the products you got and fixing them (because as-is they are broken by design), but it's your call as to whether it's worth the trouble or not. Personally, I'd return those lights or toss them into garbage where they belong.

Purchase such lights from commercial electrical suppliers that specialize or at least carry landscape lighting. They deal with professional markets and sell products you won't find in your local home improvement store. You will also expect to pay for the quality - it's not cheap.